# No Such File or Directory when Deploying Django to Elastic Beanstalk with Immutable Deployment Policy

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have already deployed my Django project to EB on AWS and it is working fine.

I tried deploying it now with an Immutable Deployment Policy and I am getting this error:

`Command failed on instance. Return code: 2 Output: python: can't open file '/opt/python/current/app/manage.py': [Errno pt/python/current/app/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.`

And that happens during the command: `source /opt/python/current/env && python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py migrate`

For some reason, I can't include that command on the first deployment.

Does anyone know how to use the immutable deployment method with Django?

Comment: Are you using Amazon Linux 1 or 2?

Comment: According to what you said on one of my previous questions, Amazon Linux 1

Comment: Ah yes. I remember now :-) I think the issue is that `current` folder does not exist yet during deployment. It ss only available when the app is deployed successful.

Comment: I don't know if this is the only solution but I am basically trying to replicate the deployment policy Heroku uses. Which I assume is deploying the new version to a new instance(s) which allows current EC2 instances to still run and once the new instances are ready, they are swapped.

Comment: That's correct, and immutable deployments are used for that.

Comment: ok, I am glad I got that right at least :-). So do you think there is a way to deploy Django apps with immutable deployments as immutable deployments are vital to production servers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218016/discussion-between-anatol-and-marcin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following:

```
source /opt/python/current/env && python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py migrate
```

is useful when you ssh into the EB instance and want to manually run your code with environmental variables.

When you deploy your EB, [container_commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) in your `.ebextensions` would be better in my view.

For example, you could have the following file  `.ebextensions/10_run_migrate.config`

```
container_commands:
  10_run_migrate:
    command: 'python ./manage.py migrate'
```

Please note that this is an example only. Thus the file may require adjustment with Django specific commands or settings.